# What is the best way to compress Elasticsearch snapshot?

Tags: logging, elasticsearch, compression, archive, snapshot

Our apps write a lot of logs like 200 GB per day. Currently our apps write logs to plain text files on shared storage. And these files compress very well using zip.

We are planning to switch to Elasticsearch + Kibana. And our tests has showed that snapshot compression using zip reduces it only for the half of original size.

What is the best way to compress daily index snapshot?

Answer (score 0):

In snapshot elasticsearch provides compress parameter which is applied only to metadata files (index mapping and settings)

**For plain text file compression you can refer the following links,**

https://superuser.com/questions/6912/highest-compression-for-filesfor-web-transfer
http://www.howtogeek.com/200698/benchmarked-whats-the-best-file-compression-format/

Comment: I am not sure how is this helpful. OPs question is how can we compress data that is being backed up using snapshot. This is controlled by ES. How can we control backing up data (not metadata) while snapshoting?

Answer (score 0):

Compression Options in Elastic Search;

1. Data is always directly [compressed](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/snapshot-and-compression/77483/2) on runtime.

   - Warning: When compressing data (in runtime), there is a space/performance trade off
   - When data store is first created, [compression level](https://www.elastic.co/blog/store-compression-in-lucene-and-elasticsearch?q=compress%20blog) can be decided by.

     *“index.codec”: “best_compression”*
2. When backing up with snapshots, because data is already compressed, only metadata and indexes will be [compressed](https://opendistro.github.io/for-elasticsearch-docs/docs/elasticsearch/snapshot-restore/).

   *"compress" : "true"*
3. There is also a "source snapshot" or "[source only repository](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/snapshots-source-only-repository.html)", in which, when backing up, only data is included, no index and no metadata will be present.

   - When restoring this snapshots, an index rebuild will be needed.